# Converting Func<> types

Tags: c#, functional-programming

```
Cannot convert type 'System.Func<int,bool>' to 'System.Func<object,bool>'
```

Trying to cast f2 to f1:

```
    Func<object, bool> f1 = x => true;
    Func<int, bool> f2 = x => true;
    f1 = (Func<object, bool>)f2;
```

Tried map function to solve but, this time i get

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'C' to 'A'
```

exception. on tranform(a) function

```
    Func<int, bool> f3 = Map(f2, x => x);

    Func<C, B> Map<A, B, C>(Func<A, B> input, Func<A, C> transform)
    {
        return x => input(transform(x));
        // return x => input(transform((A)x)); not working
    }
```

Is there a solution?

Comment: can you please explain why you need function type casting? do you want to use one function in place of another?

Comment: i need some function in a generic level component, but this function is related to implementation. and i dont want to generic-component know this implementation details. that's why i have to use this kind of casting

Comment: You are committing type errors here. It is simply not the case, that a function from int to bool is a function from anything to bool. Rethink your design.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should work:

```
f1 = p => f2((int)p);
```

Naturally, however, using this `f1` will produce an `InvalidCastException` if you pass it something that cannot be cast to an `int`.

It is possible to create a generic utility function to do this, provided the input type of `f2`  inherits from the input type of `f1` (which is true in your example - `int` derives from `object`):

```
static Func<TOut, TR> ConvertFunc<TIn, TOut, TR>(Func<TIn, TR> func) where TIn : TOut
{
    return p => func((TIn)p);
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
f1 = ConvertFunc<int, object, bool>(f2);
```

But that's not any more concise than my first example, and I think this second approach is somewhat less readable than the first one.

---

Incidentally, it is possible to get your `Map()` method to compile if you put the type arguments in the right order:

```
static  Func<TNewIn, TOut> Map<TOrigIn, TNewIn, TOut>(Func<TOrigIn, TOut> input, 
                                                      Func<TNewIn, TOrigIn> convert)
{
    return x => input(convert(x));
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
f1 = Map(f2, (object x) => (int)x);
```

You need to explicitly indicate the `NewIn` type because there's no way for the compiler to infer it.

Comment: this will not type cast the function it will rather change the implementation of f1 to f2. If I have ` Func<object, bool> f1 = x => false;` Then your method will always return true as it is no more f1 but f2. I dont think its correct answer.

Comment: @DJ Isn't that what the question is asking to do? It's trying to change the implementation of `f1` to `f2` by doing a cast on `f2`.

Comment: I never see any statement that say this.

Comment: @DJ I think it's pretty clear when he tries to use this line `f1 = (Func<object, bool>)f2;`. This (if it worked) would overwrite `f1` with `f2`. What do you think he's trying to do?